# Open 2 windows of Visual Studio Code through Terminal Mac

Tags: visual-studio-code

1. The first Visual Studio Code window is easily opened through terminal through the command **code .**
2. But going to the different folder structure and running the command **code .** doesn't open the new window rather it only makes the view go to the same visual studio code window.

**Analogy to sublime**

1. **subl .** will open a new window if one sublime window is already open with different directory.

**Edit**:
Let's say I have a project folder **abc** and a project folder **def**, I want to open both the projects in different visual studio code windows.

Going to the terminal in the folder **abc** and running command **code .** opens the folder **abc** in visual studio code window but then going to the folder **def** through terminal and running command **code .** doesn't open **def** folder in a new visual studio code window, so I have to click on New Window through Visual Studio Code and then select open folder and select **def** folder.

Answer (score 0):

You could copy the VScode app and name the copy something similar (or not) and run VScode from first terminal and then run the copy from another terminal window. You will need to add the terminal command to "/usr/local/bin" for the the terminal name of the file.

Comment: Why would I need to do all this? As I mentioned sublime, atom and other code editors already have this functionality. There should be a flag for eg -n to open a new project window.

Comment: Maybe you don't. i was just offering a simple solution if you can't find a better one. IYou didn't say if you had a time constraint or not.

Comment: the way you worded your question it sounded like you wanted to run 2 instances of VScode. Based on your comments it sounds like you just want 2 different windows running one  incidence of VScode. You can do that running new window under the file menu. i will delete my answer.